# Priming Sugar Affect on Fermentation

Tags: fermentation, sugar

I screwed up took a batch that had only been fermenting for 3 days and started to bottle it before I realized it was the wrong one. [[link](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/4858/referment-after-adding-priming-sugar)]

During this screw up I ended up added the priming sugar then putting it back to ferment.

**How will this sugar affect the fermentation process and final beer? Should I add more sugar when I go to bottle it?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Think of it this way. Sugar has a yield of [46 PPG](http://www.howtobrew.com/section2/chapter12-4-1.html) (points per pound per gallon). Say you added 1 Cup of sugar to your batch. According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sugar#Baking_weight.2Fmass_volume_relationship), that is ~7oz of sugar. If this was a 5 gallon batch, your result is that you effectively added 46*(7/16)/5 = 4 points to the original gravity of your beer. Not much to make a huge difference. Give it a week to ferment the extra sugar and then bottle it like you would have done normally.

Answer (score 3):

I would imagine the amount of sugar you added for bottling wasn't a whole lot, so I can't see it having much of an effect on the beer.

You definitely need to add more sugar at bottling time unless you don't want any carbonation.

Answer (score 3):

It wont affect the beer enough for you to notice, as long as you didnt aerate the wort when adding the priming sugar. Let it sit for a week to ferment the sugar you just added and then prime and bottle as normal.